# Symfony FOSUser Bundle - Setting failure_path for password change

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I know we can set the failure path for form_login;

```
form_login:
            provider:       fos_userbundle
            failure_path:   /register
            default_target_path: /home
```

how can i set the same structure for profile edit and password change. (profile/edit)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, No its not possible.

[form_login](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html#book-security-form-login) is handled by symfony2 not by fos_userbundle

> By specifying form_login, you have told the Symfony2 framework that
>   any time a request is made to this firewall that leads to the user
>   needing to authenticate himself, the user will be redirected to a form
>   where he will be able to enter his credentials. It should come as no
>   surprise then that you have specified the user provider service we
>   declared earlier as the provider for the firewall to use as part of
>   the authentication process.

Since symfony2 take care of security context token population, if has given way to others to set  failure path.

> But for your case, its completely in your control, then why you need
>   that setting?

I suggest you to read more about [security](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/security.html)

Comment: But the OP uses fosuserbundle!

Comment: well, whether he uses fos user bundle or his own (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html), its is just for checking credentials are correct or not. storing token  & handling failure path is done by security bundle

Comment: @artworkad may I know why my answer is not useful? let me know if anything is wrong!